# Allowing for SSH Access of Ubuntu 12.04 Server from Pubic IP

Tags: 12.04, server, ssh, ftp, openssh

I have recently configured an old PC of mine to run Ubuntu 12.04 Server to be used as an FTP Client. However, I want to find out how I can access it from a Remote Desktop (I.e: Not on the Wireless Network at Home).

Answer (score 0):

When you ssh daemon is already running you can estimate by the following command on which interface `sshd` is listening (in my case):

```
$ netstat -putan | grep sshd
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:22              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      1690/sshd
```

As you can see my ssh daemon is listening on `0.0.0.0:22` that means on every network interface at port 22. This behavior is configured in the file `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` where you can set another address to listen on by the following statement:

```
ListenAddress 1.2.3.4
```

Where `1.2.3.4` is the address to listen on. In your case you can set `0.0.0.0` or the specific public ip-address of your PC.

If your computer is behind a firewall you need to forward the port (default: 22) to your computer. But I recommend to use another port than 22, because most bots out there are trying to brute force login via ssh over port 22 as you will see in `/var/log/auth.log`.